# How to Implement publish-subscribe mechanishm to provide secure data sharing via WSO2 components

Tags: wso2, pki, xacml, data-sharing, wso2-identity-server

My project is about integration between secure data sharing and policy framework. I decided to use wso2 components for implementation.

XACML is a policy framework standart and no more thinking about. (wso2 identity server) I think the policies will manage all access control mechanishm in the project.

On the other hand I need to provide one to many encryption framework via using one of the wso2 components. XKMS is solving PKI implemetation problems. but XKMS Client doesnt help me to provide one to many (end to end) encryption requirement. And I also know I can use WSO2 WSAS as XLMS client from the bottom link. Can someone help me which could be a better solution. Thanks.

http://www.nandana.org/2008/09/xkms-features-of-wso2-web-service.html

Answer (score 0):

As i know XKMS is not much popular for key management/distribution and I do not see it in WSO2 latest products. Yes.. XACML is the standard ways to manage authorization. You can use WSO2IS as XACML engine (PAP/PDP/PIP) and integrate with your application.